# Using Twig template to generate a PDF

Tags: webforms

I am trying to generate a Twig template for the Attachment PDF item in a webform.
I am able to automatically generate a label and field data using :
`{{ webform_token('[webform:element:to]', webform) }} : {{ data.to }}`

I am trying to figure out how I can get access to the rest of the webform settings such as the labels of the different fields:
`{{ webform_token('[webform_submission:created]', webform_submission) }}`

What if I want to display the title of the form only using label:value?
I know I can use : `{{ webform_token('[webform_submission:label]', webform_submission) }}` but this gives The form name with Submission No attached to the end. I need the form name only.

Is there a command or a setting I can use to get a list of all available settings and fields in the webform?

Sorry if this is not clear enough.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I figured how to accomplish what I wanted.
It is simply a matter of selecting the proper token :)
in this case `{{ webform_token('[webform_submission:webform:title]', webform_submission) }}`